# Android SDK keep Toast from fading away

Tags: android, android-layout

Quick question: Is there a way to display a toast message that doesn't fade away until I call `cancel()` on it?

I have tried setting the `duration` to something like `9999` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to display a toast message that doesn't fade away until I call cancel() on it?

No, not directly from the SDK, but you can "tweak" your `Toast` to make it live longer by calling `show()` on it as many times you wish using threads. See [this article](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/19/indefinite-toast-hack/) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

A `Toast` that doesn't go away until you cancel it is called a `Dialog` (or `AlertDialog`). The integer you pass to `Toast.setDuration()` is a flag - not a value - it will only recognize the values `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` and `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`.

Answer (score 1):

Toast Message works with time.there is no way to control it with the cancel.You have to use [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) for the kind of purpose

Answer (score 1):

The [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) calss description says:

> "A toast is a view containing a quick little message for the user. The
> toast class helps you create and show those..."
>
> "...The idea is to be as unobtrusive as possible, while still showing the
> user the information you want them to see. Two examples are the volume
> control, and the brief message saying that your settings have been
> saved..."

As for the duration parameter it should be one of [LENGTH_LONG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_LONG) or [LENGTH_SHORT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_SHORT) - 1 or 0 respectively.

Use a dialogue that looks like a Toast if you really have to, but I don't recommend doing this because this wont be what a user expects from a Toast.

Answer (score 0):

The official doc says ([http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) ):

```
public static Toast makeText (Context context, int resId, int duration)

Since: API Level 1
Make a standard toast that just contains a text view with the text from a resource.
Parameters

context    The context to use. Usually your Application or Activity object.
resId      The resource id of the string resource to use. Can be formatted text.
duration   How long to display the message. Either LENGTH_SHORT or LENGTH_LONG
Throws     Resources.NotFoundException  if the resource can't be found.
```

This means there is no direct way to do that. You will have to build your custom code for this. As Toasts exacly overlap each other you can call the same Toast every second with a thread as an example, and use a cancel() custom method to terminate that thread.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but for others that come across it you are more than welcome to use a little library I put together called SuperToasts.

You can find the library [here](https://github.com/JohnPersano/Supertoasts).

There is an indeterminate option for Toasts that are added to an Activity namely the SuperActivityToast. I purposely did not add this feature to standard SuperToasts, a class that mimics standard Toasts, because the SuperToast can linger until your application is killed as it is added to the WindowManager and not an Activity. SuperActivityToasts are added to the Activity's content and will be destroyed along with your Activity hence the ability to make them indeterminate.