# Android toast show() method does not show again the same toast

Tags: android

I used to call the show() method on a created toast every 1s during a few seconds, to obtain a toast that stays on screen for more than LENGTH_LONG.

(Similar to [Android SDK keep Toast from fading away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751659/android-sdk-keep-toast-from-fading-away))

Note: the toast text is periodically changed while it's being displayed.

Unfortunately, it does not work anymore with Android 8.0: the toast now disappears after approximately 4s. It looks like only the 1st call to show() is working, and all subsequent calls have no effect.

I understand that it is not the intended behaviour of a Toast to stay on-screen, but before moving to another solution, I just wanted to check if this is an expected behaviour of Android 8.0 ? Maybe related to the Toast overlay attack vulnerability ?

Comment: Why you don't use SnackBar instead?

Comment: Random thought, why don't you create another toast instead of trying to make the one existing stay longer?

Comment: @E.Abdel I was more interested in the look of the toast, being in the middle of the screen

Comment: @Luzi maybe I can do that, but given the answers from Jantzilla and headuck, I fear that I will have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Android 7.1.1 each non-system package can only queue one Toast at a time. See the commit:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4ee785b698211b5ccce104e226b073ffbb12df55

Furthermore, even if you bypass the Toast mechanism and add `TYPE_TOAST` window directly, you will end up with a "bad token exception" if you add a `TYPE_TOAST` window more than once at a time. This is to enforce the policy that toast windows can only be displayed for a limited time (3.5s to be precise).

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/dc24f93%5E%21/

(Note the changes to `WindowManagerService.java`. A return of `WindowManagerGlobal.ADD_DUPLICATE_ADD` causes exception to be thrown at an upper level)

So yes, the behavior is intended.

Answer (score 0):

Android has taken steps to prevent malicious toast overlay that can trick users into granting unnecessary permissions or running other unwanted code. So it makes sense that a persistent icon is prevented from being shown.

However, I have also come across a SO question regarding an undesired text "blending effect" in Android Oreo `Toast` discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50062913/toasts-overlap-issue-on-oreo-8-1).

Therefore it seems that at some point Oreo has allowed for subsequent immediate `Toast` calls and it may not be the default behavior just yet.